# Razor Pages Not Showing The Html Its Intended To Show

Tags: asp.net-core

I gotta give you guys some info

Here is my program.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "parks",
            pattern: "Parks/{id}/{action=Details}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Park" });

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Here is my a portion of my navbar on my _layouts page:
(this is inside of a ul)

```
 @if (ViewData["ParksList"] != null)
 {
     var parksList = ViewData["ParksList"] as List<Park>;
     @foreach (var park in parksList)
     {
         <li>
             `<a href="/Parks/@park.Id/Details" class="dropdown-item">`
                 <picture>
                     <source media="(min-width:768px)" srcset="@park.DropdownImage">   @* srcset="https://www.dolphincoveja.com/Content/img/menu/ocho-rios-menu-desk.jpg" *@
                     <img src="#" alt="@park.ParkName Menu" width="134" height="128">
                 </picture>
                 <p>@park.ParkName</p>
             </a>
         </li>
     }
 }
 else
 {
     <p>No parks available.</p>
 }
```

The goal here is to loop thru all the parks i have in a table and display it in the nav bar. Note, this line's `<a href="/Parks/@park.Id/Details" class="dropdown-item">` routing. It's supposed to direct me to a particular razor page.

I have a folder in the root called Parks and in that I have some subfolders named 1,2,3,... to match whatever id is inside the parks table. Inside each of these numbered folders is a razor page called Details.cshtml and on each of these I have some custom styled razor pages.

The issue now is, when i click on one of the parks in the navbar, it doesnt take me to these pages (or it does) it shows me the actual parks details page. It's as if I was on the index page of park and clicked the details action button of one of the entries.

How can I sort this out so that the html (and css) that I wrote, show up instead

Comment: Do you mean you don't want your `Details` page use the default layout template? You don't want this page use it's own layout instead of loading default layout template? If it is , try to add `@{
    Layout = null;
}` to your page.

Comment: @XinranShen just tried that and it had no effect. do u think it could be because in my program.cs file i specified 'pattern: 
" Parks/{id}/{action=Details}",
defaults: new { controller = "Park" }); ' ? It seems to be using the controller when that really isnt what I intended

Comment: I am not sure why you create own route template, Use the  default can also route to `Parks/xx/Details`.